# SOSL return failing manage package

Tags: community, managed-package, lightning-web-components, sosl, dynamic-sosl

SOSL running fine on lower instances with no namespace getting failed in manage package.Although the SOSL EXECUTE returns rows but final output always remains 0. Working fine on unmanage.

```
searchQuery = 'FIND \'' + searchString + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING customobject__c( a__c,b__c';
                    searchQuery += ' where Status__c=: status  and Category__c=:searchType order by Category__c ASC ';
                    searchQuery += ' limit 2000 )';
                    system.debug(searchQuery);
                    List<List<customobject__c>> fnlOp = search.query(searchQuery);
                    system.debug('O/P coming empty : '+fnlOp);
                    newList = (List<customobject__c>)searchConLead[0];
                    totalCount=newList.size();
```

**Debug logs:**

```
String status ='Online'; 
           |VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[]|searchType|"Security"
           SOSL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[]|FIND 'credit/debit ' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING customobject__c(a__c,b__c  where PublishStatus__c=: status 
   and Category__c=:searchType order by Category__c ASC  limit 2000 )
           |SOSL_EXECUTE_END|[]|Rows:2
       SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[]|System.debug(ANY)
       |USER_DEBUG|[]|DEBUG|O/P coming empty : (())
       |[]|totalCount|0
```

Comment: Did you check all labels and field-level permissions to see if they were packaged correctly?

Comment: Yep all been given as normal SOQL is working fine .

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it needs the namespace of the managed package as described here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008xoRIAQ

Have you tried something like this:

```
   searchQuery = 'FIND \'' + searchString + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING namespace__customobject__c( a__c,b__c';
                searchQuery += ' where namespace__Status__c=: status  and namespace__Category__c=:searchType order by namespace__Category__c ASC ';
                searchQuery += ' limit 2000 )';
                system.debug(searchQuery);
                List<List<customobject__c>> fnlOp = search.query(searchQuery);
                system.debug('O/P coming empty : '+fnlOp);
                newList = (List<customobject__c>)searchConLead[0];
                totalCount=newList.size();
```

As described in the link?